# Unsetting an option in a systemd drop-in override

Tags: systemd, lxd

**Background:**

I have a package that provides a systemd unit file that is incompatible with LXD. Specifically, it uses the following two options, which seem to fail inside a container:

```
[Service]
IOSchedulingClass=realtime
CPUSchedulingPolicy=rr
```

So, I tried to [override these with a drop-in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services) using `systemctl edit` with the following contents:

```
[Service]
IOSchedulingClass=
CPUSchedulingPolicy=
```

But then I get the following messages in `journalctl -xe`:

```
Jun 17 18:40:14 nickel systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/freeswitch.service.d/override.conf:2] Failed to parse IO scheduling class, ignoring: 
Jun 17 18:40:14 nickel systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/freeswitch.service.d/override.conf:4] Failed to parse CPU scheduling policy, ignoring:
```

**Question:**

It seems that unsetting options like this isn't allowed. I also tried using a pair of empty quotes (e.g. `IOSchedulingClass=""`). What would be the proper way to do this? I know I can just override the whole unit file, but I'd prefer not to mask any later updates from the packaged unit file if possible.

For reference, the [`systemd.exec(5)` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#IOSchedulingClass=) suggests that there should be some way to do it:

> If the empty string is assigned to this option, all prior assignments to both IOSchedulingClass= and IOSchedulingPriority= have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a bug, but I'd try

```
[Service]
IOSchedulingClass=best-effort
CPUSchedulingPolicy=other
```

to work around it. Those are the default values, taken from the `ioprio_set` and `sched_setscheduler` manpages.

You can, of course, also override the entire unit file by putting one with the same name in `/etc/systemd/system/`. Sensible to avoid doing this as its surely more maintenance work (though you could probably script it as part of your container build).

Comment: Not sure if it was a bug or just a feature that hadn't been added yet, but in either case, [it sounds like it should work in recent versions of systemd (>=239)](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2019-June/042946.html) if you want to add that to your answer. The workaround using the default values seems to have done the trick just as well, though.